# MarkLogic Facets and Range Indexes

Tags: marklogic

I have created an application using the Application Builder in MarkLogic,
I need to add some facets in order to display the contents of the file or database, in the search engine.
Can someone please help as to how to add range indexes to drive the facets in the Application?

Thanks in Advance
Swapneel

Comment: Are you referring to [Fields in the MarkLogic sense](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_40202) (Application Builder doesn't provide a way to make Fields), or something more general? Perhaps you want to [build facets](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder/wizard#id_49161)? If you just want to control how results are displayed, look at [the Results tab](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder/wizard#id_46445).

Comment: @Dave Cassell:Thanks.
I need a way to how to define these facets in back end, and where to define it, so that they reflect or can be found in the application builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build facets, you need range indexes that the facets can draw on. From `http://localhost:8000/appservices`, you can use App Services to build the indexes. Near the top of the window, select your content database, then click Configure. In the window that appears, click "Add New" under "Range Indexes". You'll get a dialog that will help you with the indexes. When you have finished that, go back to Application Builder and click the 'Resample' button so that Application Builder knows to check for new indexes.

Other ways: You can also use the Admin UI on port 8001. Reading the [Range Indexes and Lexicons](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index) section of the Administrator's Guide will help you here.

Longer term, you'll want to script the creation of indexes (and other configuration) to ensure consistent configuration across different environments. You can script it directly with the [Management API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management), or you can use an existing tool, like [Roxy](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy) or [ml-gradle](https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-gradle).